# Linq and work with Datetime?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to do this :

```
context.Ads.Where(c => c.PublishedDate.HasValue &&
        c.EndDate.HasValue &&
        c.EndDate.Value.AddTicks(c.PublishedDate.Value.Ticks) > currentTime &&
        c.AdStatusMail.Where(b => b.StatusKey != (int)AdStatusMailKey.EndedRemainder && b.StatusKey != (int)AdStatusMailKey.MiddleRemainder).Count() < 1)
        .ToList();
```

The problem is that AddTicks can´t be used in Linq. I have looked at the EntityFunctions but can´t see how to use it to do what I need?

Comment: Entity Framework of LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IQueryable can't handle the ticks, make it IEnumerable (or tolist). Here is an example:

```
context.Ads.Where(c => c.PublishedDate.HasValue && c.EndDate.HasValue && c.AdStatusMail.Where(b => b.StatusKey != (int)AdStatusMailKey.EndedRemainder && b.StatusKey != (int)AdStatusMailKey.MiddleRemainder).Count() < 1)
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Where (c => c.EndDate.Value.AddTicks(c.PublishedDate.Value.Ticks) > currentTime)
           .ToList();
```